# django serializer thumbnail of ImageField using sorl

Tags: django, amazon-s3, serialization, sorl-thumbnail

I have an existing serializer which includes an ImageField which can be very large image. I want to have a smaller thumbnail version of that image.
I am trying to use sorl to create the thumbnails, since its able to upload it to AWS S3. How can I create this thumbnails in the serializer?

in my current serializers.py:

```
class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ("id", 
                    "username", 
                    "first_name",
                    "last_name",
                    "face_image",)
```

my model looks like this, it uploads to AWS S3:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False)   
    face_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_to('employee/face_image/'), blank=True, null=True, storage=MediaStorage())
```

This is an attempt to have a new field in the serializer called "face_image_small", but it doesnt work

```
  from sorl.thumbnail import get_thumbnail
  class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = Employee
            fields = ("id", 
                        "username", 
                        "first_name",
                        "last_name",
                        "face_image",
                        "face_image_small",)

        face_image_small = get_thumbnail(self.face_image, '200x200', crop='center', quality=99)
```

Comment: It's been a while since I used it, but I'll check when I get home. I think I have some code for it somewhere

Comment: I just got on and checked for it, and I don't have it anymore... sorry :/
I'll have to see if I can remember what I did, but I vaguely remember doing something similar... especially I have to do it for my current project soon lol

Answer (score 2):

here is my fix for this:

```
  from sorl.thumbnail import get_thumbnail
  class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = Employee
            fields = ("id", 
                        "username", 
                        "first_name",
                        "last_name",
                        "face_image",
                        "face_image_small",)

    face_image_small = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_face_image_small(self, obj):

        return face_image_small = get_thumbnail(self.face_image, '200x200', crop='center', quality=99).url
```